# Power BI over tabular - make field as web url

Tags: url, web, hyperlink, powerbi, tabular

I have Power BI connected live to SSAS tabular. There is a field in the model which I need it to work as hyperlink. The option to change it's data type to web url in PBI modeling tab is greyed out since the model is in Tabular.

How can I make the field to be a hyperlink?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change data category to WEB URL
[image: Column properties]

Answer (score -2):

Found it!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywaTxQKchx8

It can be changed in ssas --> reporting properties --> data category.